# changing yoast title using wpseo_title function

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

I'm trying to set the title of the page (made by custom theme)
This is my code, but for some reason it not getting the "$forumId" parameter

```
$forumId=999;
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
function filter_product_wpseo_title() {
        return 'My id= '. $forumId  ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set $forumId as global variable. See updated code below.

```
global $forumId;
$forumId=999;
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
function filter_product_wpseo_title() {
        global $forumId;
        return 'My id= '. $forumId  ;
}
```